# How can I use Target-specific Variable Values and call other rules whilst using parallel execution?

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, gnu-make

I have a makefile with the following lines:

```
debug: CFLAGS += $(DEBUGFLAGS)
debug: clean all
```

What I want to do is run 'clean' and 'all' with the Target Specific Variable values. This works fine and as expected.

But if I ran this with parallel execution 'clean' might destroy the files being create by 'all'.

So if I do something like the following:

```
debug: CFLAGS += $(DEBUGFLAGS)
debug:
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) all
```

This will ensure that the order of the rules is respected. But the Target Specific Variables will not be taken into the new invocations of make.

So I was wondering how I can use both Target Specific Variables and parallel execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just pass through the values as well?

```
debug: CFLAGS += $(DEBUGFLAGS)
debug:
        $(MAKE) clean CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)'
        $(MAKE) all CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)'
```

Comment: Hi! This works well. I didn't know you could do this. To clarify, when I do this is the variable CFLAGS not edited by the new invocation of make?

Comment: Also is the parallel execution flag included in the '$(MAKE) all ...' call, if not how would you add it (only if it is being called in parallel)?

Comment: It is not edited.  Command line variable settings override any setting in the makefile.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Values.html

Comment: As long as you use the `$(MAKE)` (or `${MAKE}`) variables in the recipe rather than invoking the raw `make` command, all relevant flags and other command line settings from the parent make will be passed to its sub-makes.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of make introduced it (3.8? 4.0?), but if you add 'clean' to the pseudo-target .NOTPARALLEL, then clean is not run in parallel, and other targets are. I use make -j clean all and this seems to work as expected.

e.g.

```
...<variables defined here>...

all: $(TARGETS)
clean:; rm -rf $(TARGETS) ...

...<rules defined here>...

.PHONY: all clean
.NOTPARALLEL: clean
```